# install Java SE SDK 5 on Chromebook

Tags: linux, java, chromebook

So I turned on the developer mode, installed Crouton on my Samsung Chromebook and used it as a linux ever since and it's been great. Now I need to install Java SE SDK 5(maybe 4 also) to perform some tasks.
However I couldn't get it working.
Here is what I did: I went [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html) to download. But I'm not really sure which one because there's no arm option. So I tried all the bin files and all failed with this error:

```
./install.sfx.3940 ELF: not found
```

Which I think means it can't be identified as a binary file. I used `uname -a` on the terminal and here is what I got:

```
Linux localhost 3.8.11 #1 SMP Mon Jun 9 01:33:13 PDT 2014 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Now I'm wondering: is there a corresponding SDK for my machine at all?

Comment: [JDK 8 for ARM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-arm-downloads-2187472.html).  I doubt you'll be able to get older versions.

Comment: JDK 8 (linked by heavyd above) should be backwards-compatible for running Java 5 and Java 4 code/applications.